# How to resolve java: package org.junit.jupiter.api does not exist and package org.springframework.boot.test.context does not exist

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm trying to learn SpringBoot and I've not been able to resolve this issue for the past several days, I try to run my `DemoApplication` class, and encounter these messages
`package org.junit.jupiter.api does not exist`
`package org.springframework.boot.test.context does not exist`
`cannot find symbol class SpringBootTest`
`cannot find symbol class Test`
Unfortunately, no tutorials online seem to encounter this issue, and I've not found any helpful guides.
I'm using IntelliJ IDEA, and I'm on SpringBoot 2.7.11. I ran into the same issue with 3.0.6.

My pom.xml is as follows

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.11</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example.sbpractice</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Just Google the names of the missing classes + which jar.

Comment: Are you following a tutorial or something like that? How you choose those dependencies? Is your IDE the one that shows that message? Are you running maven from the command line?

Comment: Could you please elaborate more on how you are running the program? Most likely this has caused due to  a missing dependency. However, it is better to show all the steps you took in the question.

Comment: Just met the same problem on Idea 2023.2 #IU-232.8660.185. No solution found, had to downgrade the app version.

Comment: @Andrey i manadged to fix this issue buy re-add maven project in idea
source: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/11333307374994-Maven-Dependency-not-recognized-by-IntelliJ?page=1#community_comment_11338231269266